# How can I set columns of a dataframe as x-axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

```
                  Time  Volume
Index                         
0      16:18:40.505530       1
1      16:18:40.510560       1
2      16:18:40.524660       1
3      16:18:40.693910       1
4      16:18:40.900390       2
5      16:18:40.902290       1
6      16:18:41.296110       4
7      16:18:41.898610       1
8      16:18:42.099940       1
9      16:18:42.303210       3
10     16:18:42.497490       1
11     16:18:43.095560       1
.....

>> df.Time
....   
Name: Time, Length: 103248, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

My goal is to plot this data and set the **index** and **Time column** as x-axes.
I can easily plot it if it's only with the index as x-axis, like this.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.scatter(df.index,df.Volume, marker='+', s=1 )
```

but I don't know how I can add another x-axis using Time column.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to have a double x-axis?

If you want to present them both  - try concatenating the value.
If you wish that the time will be the x-axis just run:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.scatter(df.Time,df.Volume, marker='+', s=1 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I plot the graph with my original code, it only shows index numbers on the x-axis and I want to add another x-axis using Time column. I tried your code, but it shows an error. `TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') according to the rule 'same_kind`